# Questions about Zorn's lemma

Tags: set-theory

Zorn's lemma states that: Suppose a partially ordered set P has the property that every chain in P has an upper bound in P. Then the set P contains at least one maximal element.

Suppose $P$ satisfies the assumption to apply the Zorn's lemma. Does it then follow that given any $x \in P$ there exists a maximal element $m \in P$ such that $x \leq m$?

ps also by chain I thought it was of the form $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3...$
Is this correct? Thank you

Comment: hint: consider the subposet $P'$ of $P$ consisting of all elements greater than or equal to $x$, and show that the hypotheses of Zorn's apply apply to $P'$

Comment: For the PS: A chain is, by definition, a totally ordered subset.  It need not be countable.  If $C$ is a chain, this means: for any $x,y \in C$, either $x \le y$ or $y \le x$ (or both).

Answer (score 0):

YES.

Set $\,Y=\{y\in X: x\le y\}$. Then $Y$ inherits the partial order of $X$, and every chain $S\subset Y$, is also a chain of $X$, and hence possesses an upper bound $y_M$ in $X$. Clearly $x\le y_M$ and hence $y_M\in Y$. Therefore one may apply Zorn's Lemma in $Y$ as well.

Any maximal element $m$ of $Y$ satisfies $x\le m$.